# Convert a array of strings into string for the csv

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, stringify

I have following array of strings.

```
 const test = ["Date,type,user,Account,Desc\r",
    "1 jan 2021,RR,GK,,Testing acc\r",
    "1 jan 2021,RR,GK,,Testing acc\r",
    "1 jan 2021,RR,GK,,Testing acc\r",
    "1 jan 2021,RR,GK,,Testing acc\r"]
```

Now I am trying to convert this array of string into the a single string which can then used for CSV creation.

So I tried `test.toString()` which resulted into

```
"Date,type,user,Account,Desc
,1 jan 2021,RR,GK,,Testing acc
,1 jan 2021,RR,GK,,Testing acc
,1 jan 2021,RR,GK,,Testing acc
,1 jan 2021,RR,GK,,Testing acc
"
After using this data for CSV creation , it is actually skipping one column means Date date gets added in the next column and last data which is Testing acc does not contain any header it should have been Desc.
```

If I remove the the `,` before every `1 jan 2021` then it takes all columns properly but the date should have been `######` instead it takes the original value.

How do I fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: What about `.join(‘’)`?

Comment: After using .join I am able to see data in a proper rows but the date is not getting as ##### it is the date in the format given in data

Comment: Why should the date change? You’re not doing anything to it.

Comment: Okay.. Its woring with join , How do I use it with `` directly.

Comment: Please try to write down an expected output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the join method:

```js
const separator = '\n'; // or select enother value
test.join(separator)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: Sorry it does not work.. It still gives the date as in the given formant and not in as ######

Comment: What does the ###### format mean?

Comment: do you mean YYMMDD?